# Can we join hop and hops tags

Tags: support, tags

"hop" tag has only 7 questions, while "hops" has over one hundred. I do not see a point in keeping the singular form, since most of the times the plural form "hops" is used, can we delete "hop" and just use "hops"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds good to me.  merged and made hop a synonym.

Comment: agreed.........